# How Can I Include An Ignored File In Checkout/Clone?

Tags: git

I want to have a local settings file in git with a list of variables in it (maybe with defaults) that the developer will need to change for working locally.

This is easier than telling the developers what all the variables they need to have and which file to put it in as it avoids "magic" configuration.

However, if I commit this local configuration file, it will always be marked as modified when developers are working locally, which I want to avoid.

This will also happen if I have it in the .gitignore in one commit and the file in another commit as git will be aware of it and still track it.

If I do `git rm --cached` it will also delete the file which is not what I want to do.

I was thinking of creating it with a hook but these are local and not created as part of `git clone`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As [the Git FAQ outlines](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files), you cannot ignore tracked files.  Git doesn't allow this because it's impossible to know what to do with such files and the often-proposed solutions using `git update-index` don't work.

However, the FAQ offers a suggestion:

> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

If you like, you can use a script to perform this copying and modification.